# How to Enable Multirow Bookmarks Toolbar?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, firefox-extensions

I have tried using Multirow Bookmarks Toolbar Plus and Roomy Bookmarks Toolbar Firefox add-ons, but the problem is that they are constantly stressing my CPU (even when idling). It probably has something to do with version 11 of the browser. Anyway, **is there some clean way to increase the height of the bookmarks toolbar and allow it to display bookmarks on multiple rows?**

I've read a lot of articles that refer to userChrome.css and I have tried a dozen solutions, but none worked because they were outdated. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following userchrome trick seem to work. Easiest way to edit userchrome is by using [stylish addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). Install the addon and goto Add-ons > User Styles > Write New Style. And paste the following code.

```
.bookmark-item {
  margin: 5px 2px 10px 2px !important;
  font-size: 15px !important; 
}
```

Change the values as you need and click on preview to view it. Then save it. 
For `margin:` changing first and third pixel value will change the height. The `font-size:` line will change the font size of the bookmark text. Remove it if not needed. You can enable/disable this anytime you want without restarting firefox through stylish.

Comment: Thank you, Nufail. That indeed helped increasing the height of the bookmarks toolbar, but I was looking for a way to enable multi-row bookmarks toolbar. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Found an article here that shows some code which can be used with the useful add-on you linked me to. It enabled multi-row bookmarks toolbar, but the CPU still gets stressed because of it, so I guess it is a Firefox thing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The one available directly seems to be bugged, but please try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multirow-bookmarks-toolbarplus/)